# Osazone crystal structures

Tags: organic-chemistry, crystal-structure, carbohydrates

What is the reason behind the formation of different shapes of crystals for different osazones? Like glucose osazone- needle shaped, maltose osazone- sunflower shaped, lactose osazone - powderpuff shaped. Does this involves hydrogen bonds only or something else? If so then can I be able to determine the crystal shape of different osazones by simple calculations?